# Struts2 radio: preset value if model is not set

Tags: jsp, struts2, radio-button, struts-tags

I have a radio tag in my form page. By default, "No" is selected.

```xml
<s:radio label="Yes NO" name="accept" list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}" value="'N'"/>
```

But if I select Yes and save the form to the database and re-render, then the radio is still showing 'No' while the database and the accept property are set to: 'Yes'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `value="'N'"` you are forcing the value to ALWAYS be N.

You need to read the value dynamically from an attribute, pre-setting it in the action:

```java
private String accept;

public String getAccept(){
    if (accept==null) { accept = "N"; }
    return accept;
}
```

```xml
<s:radio label="Yes NO" name="accept" list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}" value="%{accept}"/>
```

or even cleaner, remove the value attribute at all:

```xml
<s:radio label="Yes NO" name="accept" list="#{'Y':'Yes','N':'No'}" />
```

and it will preset it with the name attribute.